# PyQt font size changes with windows display configurations

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working on a PyQt4 GUI. During testing I recognized that the font size of all QLabels changes on diffrent computers. Apprently the windows display configurations can be changed from 100% to 125% or 150%, which then changed the fontsize of my widgets.

Is there an option where I can force the GUI to keep its fontsize independently from the display settings?

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Edit:
I seached for the correct terminology, but best I get is this: If you open `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display` you can change the font- and other displayed elements-size. This configuration is independent from the screen resolution, but I dont know if it is independent from the actual dpi of the screen. Since `AA_DisableHighDpiScaling` does not work on PyQt4 I'll have to keep looking for another solution.

Comment: Qt4 is obsolete legacy code. Official support ended in December 2015. You should not be using it for new projects.

Answer (score 1):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

Looks like you could disable scaling using this snippet (did not check though):

```
QGuiApplication().setAttribute(Qt.AA_DisableHighDpiScaling)
```

Comment: Since this function was introduced with PyQt 5.6 I cannot use it in my document. `type object 'Qt' has no attribute 'AA_DisableHighDpiScaling'
` is all I get.

I am not even sure if the DPI Scaling is a problem (yet). I will further elaborate this in my Question.

Comment: @bakatrouble You should add that this line is added in your "main" which starts the app (e.g. `app.setAttribute(...)`) because this is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I thought I would add my two cents. If you want to iterate through all Qlabels and allow user to change font size, the code below works well for me (using PyQt5)

```
# change font
def font_change(self):
    font, ok = QtWidgets.QFontDialog.getFont()
    if ok:
        for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(self):
            if isinstance(obj, QtWidgets.QLabel):
                obj.setFont(font)
```

Answer (score 1):

I too struggled with this problem on a application I was working on recently.  I tired the other answers but was unable to get anything to work.  What ended up being the solution for me was to "fix" a font size for each label and button in the stylesheet editor in QT Designer.

[QT Designer Stylesheet Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCAjU.png)

[QT Designer Stylesheet Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61FGi.png)

You could also programmatically set this with the .setStyleSheet() method in the code as well.  Both solutions worked perfectly in my PyQT5 app on Windows 10.